# Where is the gesture button?

Tags: dolphin-browser

Today I can't find the gesture button. I had it placed bottom right, showing faint on every page; now I have to go to menu /dolphin to bring it up. When I look at gesture settings all I can do is add extra gestures, but no menu list or other way to restore the 'always there' button. Has quick access been removed? I'm using dolphin version 8.0.0 on galaxy note. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the Gesture Settings you need to click on the tab that says "Dolphin Sonar Settings" in the bottom right hand corner.  There you'll have the option to "Enable bottom left button."  This puts the new "dual purpose" Gesture & Sonar button in the bottom left hand corner.

FWIW, I think the whole Sonar thing is annoying and I don't understand why they reduced the customization options.  I prefer my gesture button on the right!

Answer (score 0):

The gestures icon is now multi purpose.  When you click the icon and the dolphin sonar comes up, there are two buttons on the bottom.  That will toggle between sonar and gestures, remembering which one you had setup last.